# Get Application class from event

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm building app with JavaFX 2.x. Main method is in class **Frame**, which extends JavaFX Application. Controller binded from FXML template has event (button click), which is classof **ActionEvent**.

My question is, how is all of that linked? I wanna get applicaiton instance (**Frame**) from event.

I've some dirty and ugly solution (static function to set/get app instance).... is there cleaner way?

Thanks

P.S. *I know, how to get scene, stage (window?), but don know, "where" is instance of application (place, where is main());*
P.P.S *I'm n00bee in JavaFX technology*

Comment: You should explain *why* you need a link back to the application - there might be better ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a static getter returning the [Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html) instance from your Application subclass (as you have currently implemented it).

I think other potential solutions will end up clunkier.

Comment: Huh.. that creates hardlink to Frame class. Nevermind. Thanks for reply :)